# Need to execute a piece of code repeatedly for fixed duration in java

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I have written a piece of code . How can I get that code to run for certain duration repeatedly, say for 10 second?

Answer (score 0):

The [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) seems to provide methods which execute tasks until they are either completed or else a timeout occurs (such as the [`invokeAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)).

Answer (score 0):

You can give a  try to [Quartz Job Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)

> Quartz is a richly featured, open source job scheduling library that
>   can be integrated within virtually any Java application - from the
>   smallest stand-alone application to the largest e-commerce system.
>   Quartz can be used to create simple or complex schedules for executing
>   tens, hundreds, or even tens-of-thousands of jobs; jobs whose tasks
>   are defined as standard Java components that may execute virtually
>   anything you may program them to do. The Quartz Scheduler includes
>   many enterprise-class features, such as support for JTA transactions
>   and clustering.

If you are familiar with [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) in Linux , this will be a cakewalk for you .

Answer (score 0):

Use a worker and start it in a thread, wait in the main thread for the specific time and stop the worker after this.

```
MyRunnable task = new MyRunnable();
Thread worker = new Thread(task);
// Start the thread, never call method run() direct
worker.start();

Thread.sleep(10*1000); //sleep 10s
if (worker.isAlive()) {
    task.stopPlease(); //this method you have to implement 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure why people downvoted the question. Be sure to in the future provide some sample code. Your answer however is simple here. Create a new thread to watch the wait. In simple code:

```
public class RunningClass {
     public static void runThis(){
          TimerThread tt = new TimerThread();
          tt.timeToWait = 10000;
          new Thread(tt).start();
          while (!TimerThread.isTimeOver){
                \\Code to execute for time period
          }
 }

 class TimerThread implements Runnable {

      int timeToWait = 0;
      boolean isTimeOver = false;

       @override
       public void run(){
            Thread.sleep(timeToWait);
       }
  }
```

The code above can be put in the same class file. Change the 10000 to whatever time you require it to run for.

You could use other options, but it would require you to have knowledge on workers and tasks.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what was the exact requirement, but 
if your req was to cancel only a long running task

you could use ExecutorService & Future (in jdk 5) as follows.

ExecutorService fxdThrdPl = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

```
    // actual task .. which just prints hi but after 100 mins
    Callable<String> longRunningTask = new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            try{
                TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(100); // long running task .......   
            }catch(InterruptedException ie){
                System.out.println("Thread interrupted");
                return "";                          
            }               
            return "hii"; // result after the long running task
        }
    };

    Future<String> taskResult = fxdThrdPl.submit(longRunningTask); // submitting the task
    try {

        String output = taskResult.get(***10**strong text**, TimeUnit.SECONDS***);
        System.out.println(output);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {          
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        ***taskResult.cancel(true);***
    }
```